Find $P(B_2 > 0, B_8 > 0)$
We need to compute $P(B_2 > 0, B_8 > 0)$ where $B_t$ is brownian motion
Now, $P(B_2 > 0, B_8 > 0) = P(B_2 > 0, B_8 - B_2 > -B_2) = P(Z_1 > 0, Z_2 > -Z_1)$ where $Z_1 \sim N(0, 2), Z_2 \sim N(0, 6)$ and $Z_1, Z_2$ are independent
Now if you plot $z_1 > 0, z_2 + z_1 > 0$ you'll get the first quadrant and half of the 4th quadrant. so probability from first quadrant is definitely $\frac{1}{4}$ but for the 4th quadrant since $Z_1, Z_2$ is not radially symmetric, it is not easy to calculate probability in that region, and I don't know how to calculate for ellipsoidal contours.
Any help is appreciated, although a solution without going through nasty integration would be great. Thanks

$$
P(Z_1>0,Z_2>-Z_1)=P(\sqrt 2G>0,\sqrt 6G'>-\sqrt 2G)=P(G>0,\sqrt 3G'+G>0),
$$
where $G,G'$ are two independent standard gaussian random variables. In the plane it corresponds to the region
$$
\{(x,y)\mid x>0,y>-\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}x\},
$$
or with polar coordinates,
$$
\{(r,\theta)\mid r>0,\theta\in[-\frac\pi6,\frac\pi2]\},
$$
so the probability is $\frac{1}{12}+\frac14=\frac13$.
